# How do I access an MS Access database file in Visual Basic code?

Tags: database, vb.net, data-binding

I am a student working on a point of sales program for a project and I want my program to be able to access, for example, the prices of several different items stored in the database.

I already know how to bind data to individual elements in the form window I just need to bind an item to to a specific row and column of data in the database with code. I want it to be possible to bind each item to different items in the database.

Thank You.

Comment: You don't bind controls to data in a database, you download the data, bind to the local copy and then save the changes by sending them back to the database as a separate event. Check out https://dapper-tutorial.net

Comment: @CaiusJard I need to be working with a MS Access database for this. If you can help me please.

Comment: Have you looked at Dapper? It's a library that will easily help you to download db data into your app as objects, you can bind to them and then send them back to the db when you save

Comment: you Could optionally use a much older data acces strategy - datasets; they're essentially geared up to do everything you're looking for and would make your life very easy, and in a lot of ways I think it's a shame that industry moved away from them. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms171884%28v%3dvs.100%29 - getting comfortable with them would help you transition to a modern way of doing the same thing with something like EF

Comment: @CaiusJard Can you tell me how to access a dataset in the vb.net code?

Comment: I can, but I'm not sure there would be any point me saying what Microsoft already said in that link I gave you